# AWS - IIS and Windows services and SQL server - Load balancer and High availability

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a software product made in `.Net`.

It has one Asp.net website and four Windows services.

Both Asp.net application and Windows services communicates with SQL server installed in same machine.

Right now we have hosted this product in a Windows server 2012 R2. So one  server contains one asp.net application, four windows services and a SQL server.

Now we have decided to move this infrastructure to AWS.

Basically we want to get following benefits:

1. IIS  and windows services load balancing.
2. IIS , windows service, SQL - fail over. So if one server goes down, there will be other one who can continue to serve requests.

So anyone can please provide me some links or other sort of help which can help me to get started as I am new in AWS?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a difference between load balancing and failover. Are your web applications designed so that you can load balance? Edit your question will the new information. Look into AWS ALB, ASG, RDS and Route53. This will help you improve your question. Amazon has a very good tutorial series to help you get started. Here is an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_3-Bnd18dA

Answer (score 0):

You should read the "Well Architected Framework" from AWS

https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected/

The site points to each pillar of the framework. There's also one whole whitepaper on the subject, a good read if you're seriously attempting a solution in the cloud.